# How to install/import MakieLayout

Tags: plot, package, julia

I'm trying to run this simple example, taken directly from [the official documentation](https://makie.juliaplots.org/stable/makielayout/laxis.html#Setting-Axis-Limits-and-Reversing-Axes)

```
using AbstractPlotting.MakieLayout
using AbstractPlotting

scene, layout = layoutscene(resolution = (1200, 900))

ax = layout[1, 1] = LAxis(scene, xlabel = "x label", ylabel = "y label",
    title = "Title")
```

But I get an error at line 1: `MakieLayout not defined`

I have successfully installed `Makie` (v0.11.0) and `AbstractPlotting` (v0.11.2). I still managed to run the example by installing and importing `MakieLayout` as a separate package but `MakieLayout` as a package is deprecated and should have been absorbed by `AbstractPlotting`.

My questions are:

- Am I doing something wrong here?
- Is this an isolated issue or do other people have the same problem?

I would really appreciate some help if someone knows what is going on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AbstractPlotting's current version (Nov 5 2020) is 0.13.5. I recommend updating it before trying to use `AbstractPlotting.MakieLayout`.

You can update this package by doing

```
] update AbstractPlotting
```

If it is not correctly updated, it is possible that some other package is holding it back.

To discover what package is holding it back you can try to add the specific version by doing

```
] add AbstractPlotting@0.13.5
```

And you will get a more informative error message.

I advice you to remove the `MakieLayout` package before updating since this is obsolete and it is probably holding AbstractPlotting's version back.

**EDIT (6 November 2020):**
Nowadays it is not necessary to install the Makie.jl package. You can safely remove it and add instead:

- AbstractPlotting

And one or more of the backends:

- GLMakie (`] add GLMakie`), the fastest and more complete, uses GPU
- CairoMakie (`] add CairoMakie`) if you don't have GPU or want to output to vector graphics
- WGLMakie (`] add WGLMakie`)

the package called `Makie` is just AbstractPlotting + GLMakie and I think it is on its way out. You should remove the package and change your first line to:

```
using AbstractPlotting, GLMakie #or your selected backend
using AbstractPlotting.MakieLayout
```

Information about managing versions and packages can be found [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Pkg/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, apparently my problem is makie, and I cant't update it : `possible versions are: [0.9.0-0.9.6, 0.10.0, 0.11.0-0.11.1] or uninstalled`

Comment: You can safely remove Makie and just add AbstractPlotting and one backend. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in accepting your answer, and thanks you very much!